# Git merge branch without into

Tags: git

What does it mean when i look at git log and see something like this:

```
Merge branch 'wtf' of my.site.com:~/repo
```

Usually It looks like this:

```
Merge branch 'wtf' of my.site.com:~/repo into some-other-branch
```

Which makes perfect sense to me.

Note, this particular repo is in a detatched head state and has apparently been this way for some time.  I suspect this is the reason for the strange commit message.

Comment: Being in a detached HEAD state for some time isn't good. You can fix that by making a branch right now. It's just a label.

Comment: this is also good advice, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the current branch is `master` the branch is not mentioned in the merge commit message.

Answer (score 1):

As explained above by [phd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976758/phd) this is the correct answer.
Let's give some more details into it.

Whenever you merge 2 or more branches and the merge will result in a `merge commit` (for example when `--no-ff` merge occurs) git will generate the commit message for you. `merge commit` is the case when your commits are not producing a straight line, its when you have "derived" from your main commit lines and the merge should add the code back to your "main" line. It will result in a split log graph.

The commit message will include the names of the branches in the format *`Merge branch X into Y`*. If the **current** branch is master, meaning that you merge code into master, **git will not add the `master` to your commit message**.

---

#### `ff` merge (no merge commit)

[image]

#### `--no-ff` merge (merge commit)

[image]